# Why is pip installing Pillow for OS X 10.12, when I have OS X 10.11 installed?

Tags: python, macos, pip, python-imaging-library

When trying to import PIL (using Pillow), I get the following error:

```
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import Image
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 60, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib
```

Note the line `Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/liblzma.5.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)` and specifically  '**(which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)**'.

I have a hunch that I may have corrupted something when I attempted to manually install the wrong version of xCode (not compatible with 10.11.6, which is on this computer). I have installed Pillow using `pip install Pillow` - but that installation resulted in this error. Is there a way to force pip to install a certain version of Pillow, to see if the problem lies in pip installing a problematic version?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in the latest Pillow 5.1.0 release.

It was caused by upgrading Xcode from version 8 to 9.2 for building the binary wheels.

El Capitan 10.11 is the "min macOS to run" for Xcode 8.

Sierra 10.12.6 is the min for Xcode 9.2.

[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-*9.x*(since_Free_On-Device_Development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#Xcode_7.0_-_9.x_(since_Free_On-Device_Development)

There will be a Pillow 5.1.1 out to fix it at some point.

In the meantime, the workaround is: pip install 'pillow!=5.1.0'

(Or upgrade your macOS, or build from source.)

For more info, see https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3068

Comment: Thank you for the workaround, this sounds exactly like the symptoms of my issue. I’ll try it ASAP.

Comment: In 2023, matplotlib 3.6.2 -> PIL 9.4.0 on macos 10.14.6 gives a similar dlopen error.
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/6179
has a nice table that says "macos 10.14 is not supported, upgrade to 10.15";
sigh, versionitis ...

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like the wheel uploaded to PyPI was not built for your platform correctly. Unfortunately having the wheel for a PyPI package for your platform is not a guarantee that the wheel will install or work correctly, you're at the mercy of the PyPI package maintainer in this regard.

You should run `pip uninstall Pillow`, download the source directly from PyPI, build it manually and run `pip install -e <path to rebuilt package>` to install the wheel you built specifically for your machine.

Comment: Do you mean to download, build and install the `wheel` module (wrong word?) that I see when I do `pip list`? Or to download, build and install the Pillow wheel? ... because I found the Pillow wheel [here](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files), but haven't found how to build and reinstall `wheel` (which is currently showing as v 0.31.0).

Comment: Also, should I be using the .whl file, or should I use the `source` file? I realize this might sound like a stupid question, but I'm brand new to working with python and this wheel notion...

Comment: The source is the .tar.gz file listed among these files; https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/#files

A wheel is a file with binary libraries used by pip to install a package without requiring a build. This allows users to install packages on computers that don't have a compiler.