# Problem with Python PIL/dylib and compatibility with macOS

Tags: python, macos, manim

**EDIT:** Please check the comment I wrote below

I am running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 and I think I have downloaded a version for PIL library(using brew install py3cairo probably) that is not compatible with my OS. The computer has also pre-installed python2.
I have installed ffmpeg and I have it stored in documents, with some help, I have placed it in path so when I type in terminal:

```
>>> echo $PATH
```

the output is:
`Users/imac/Documents/ffmpeg:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin`

My terminal's output when I run a simple program that is supposed to work(copy-paste from tutorial for manim):

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
...(omitted)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 132, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/_imaging.cpython-39-darwin.so, 
2): Symbol not found: ____chkstk_darwin
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libtiff.5.dylib 
(which was built for Mac OS X 11.0)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/.dylibs/libtiff.5.dylib```
````

Comment: I think I found a relative topic here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969800/why-is-pip-installing-pillow-for-os-x-10-12-when-i-have-os-x-10-11-installed.
I don't know if the answers apply to my case I have python3 and mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6. I suspect the 2nd answer may be more suitable but I still need guidance. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you try any of those answers?

Comment: Can you guide me on building manually the wheel, that is referred in the 2nd answer of that post? I downloaded the `source` / the .tar.gz file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problem solved :)

So the steps I followed were:

1. `>>> pip3 uninstall Pillow`
2. `>>> brew install libjpeg libtiff little-cms2 openjpeg webp`
3. `>>> python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
4. `>>> python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow --no-binary :all:`

Reasoning and more details can be found here:
https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#building-on-macos

*Note:* from the second answer of the linked post [Why is pip installing Pillow for OS X 10.12, when I have OS X 10.11 installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969800/why-is-pip-installing-pillow-for-os-x-10-12-when-i-have-os-x-10-11-installed)
, I borrowed the 1st command for uninstalling.